# Telerik MVC specifying your own action router within a template column

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I am using the latest version of `Telerik MVC` with `ASP.NET MVC 3` and the `Razor` view engine.

I have the following column declaration:

```
column.Bound(x => x.Id)
   .Template(x => Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = x.Id }))
   .Title("Action")
   .Width(100);
```

I have created my own method that routes to this Edit action method which I would like to use but not sure how to?

```
public static object AdministrationCategoryEdit(this UrlHelper urlHelper, int categoryId)
{
   Check.Argument.IsNotNull(urlHelper, "urlHelper");

   return new { area = "Administration", controller = "Category", action = "Edit", id = categoryId };
}
```

How would I reference the above method in my column declaration and pass it through the category ID?

For example, if I want to use it with a button, then I would do something like:

```
$('#btnEdit').click(function () {
   window.location = '@Url.RouteUrl(Url.AdministrationCategoryEdit(Model.Id))';
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no perfect match for your requirement since all `ActionLink` methods have a separate parameter for the action. However, it should work with the following code even though the action is now specified twice.

```
column.Bound(x => x.Id)
   .Template(x => Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", Url.AdministrationCategoryEdit(x.Id)))
   .Title("Action")
   .Width(100);
```

An alternative would be to create an HTML helper similar to `ActionLink` that now only generates the route parameters but the complete code for a link.

Comment: Thanks.  I thought just as much to create a helper method.